# An empty string is a null reference?

Tags: c#, string, winforms, nullreferenceexception, versioninfo

Why would this code (in my form's `_Load()` event):

```
FileVersionInfo vi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(_fullPath);
String VersionInfo = vi.FileVersion;
if (VersionInfo.Trim().Equals(String.Empty)) {
    VersionInfo = NO_VERSION_INFO_AVAILABLE;
}
textBoxVersionInfo.Text = VersionInfo;
```

...give me the following err msg when `VersionInfo == ""` is true?

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>     Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Comment: Why not use `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(VersionInfo)) ...` to cover both your bases?

Comment: Do you know the exact line of code this is failing on?

Comment: @Steve: Yes, on the "Equals" line. I moved the code to the Shown() event, and it works fine there.

Comment: @Bridge: Because I forgot about that; thanks for the reminder, I'll change it to IsNullOrEmpty().

Comment: @ClayShannon That may not solve it of course, it might be something else that's null!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `null`-safe way to do this: instead of

```
VersionInfo.Trim().Equals(String.Empty)
```

write

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(VersionInfo)
```

It will not crash if `VersionInfo` is null, and it will return true if trimming `VersionInfo` results in an empty string.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` method here. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(VersionInfo)) {
    VersionInfo = NO_VERSION_INFO_AVAILABLE;}
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, since I was getting a ridiculous number of down votes on my other question, here it is again in a more blunt and less lighthearted fashion:

- **`null` represent the *lack* of an object**; and
- **all strings are objects**; thus
- **there is no string, of any length, which is `null`**; thus
- ***an empty string is never `null`.***

That's it, nothing more. *Examine the stack-trace* and/or *attach a debugger* to find out *where* the `null` (which is *not* an empty string) is coming from.

The exception is the result of using `expr.somePropertyFieldOrMethod` where `expr` evaluates to `null`<sup>1</sup> hence the ***Null Reference*** Exception.

It is the job of *you*, the developer, to find out *which* `expr` was `null` instead of waiting to see what others suggest might be wrong. As such, I am closing this as "too localized" after answering the question in the title, which is the only question present.

(As in my previous answer, I note that `textBoxVersionInfo` being `null` could cause this exception, even when `VersionInfo == ""` is true. The other alternative is, of course, that *that* `VersionInfo` does *not* represent the empty string.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Technically this exception could be raised arbitrarily, perhaps justified in an Extension Method. However, raising this exception wantonly is *not* common or good practice or found in the .NET framework and is thus generally a dismissible cause when debugging.

Answer (score 2):

If `VersionInfo is NULL` is true then **VersionInfo.Trim()** will give an error.

please use `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

If VersionInfo is null, then you can check it with

```
if(VersionInfo == null)
```

or

`String.IsNullOrEmpty(VersionInfo)`

Comment: "VersionInfo is not an Object" What is `VersionInfo` then, if not an object? It can't be `null`...

Comment: if `vi.FileVersion` is null then VersionInfo may be null, i think.

Comment: This is wrong.  If `versionInfo == ""` is true, then `VersionInfo.Trim()` will return the empty string.  It is also incorrect to say "VersionInfo is null in that case".

Answer (score 1):

After your response to my comment, you know that `VersionInfo` is null.  The call to Trim() is failing because that will execute before the check if it equals `String.Empty`.

You should use `(string.IsNullOrEmpty(VersionInfo) || VersionInfo.Trim().Length < 1)` instead (or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(VersionInfo)` if you're in .NET 4).

**EDIT:**

After seeing your response to another answer that you removed Trim() and it still doesn't work...at that point, it's the Equals call that will break.  Try the code mentioned above and it should work fine.

Comment: What solved this problem was simply moving the code from the Load() event to the Shown() event. Load() is apparently just too early in the life[cycle,time] for some properties to be safely accessed.